# Python changing list element based on value being odd or even

Tags: python, list

Supposed to change a value of a list based on if the value is odd or even. 
Error:

```
list assignment index out of range
```

Code:

```
def list_mangler(list_in):
    for i in list_in:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            list_in[i] = i * 2
        else:
            list_in[i] = i * 3
    return list_in



list_mangler([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 4):

the problem is that `for i in list_in` yields *items* in the list, not *indices*.  To get the indices, use `enumerate`:

```
for i, val in enumerate(list_in):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        list_in[i] = val * 2
    ...
```

If you wanted to return a *new* list (rather than mutating the old list), a list comprehension with a conditional expression could do nicely:

```
[val * 3 if val % 2 else val * 2 for val in list_in]
```

And of course, you can use this with slice assignment to mutate `list_in` if you really need to:

```
list_in[:] = [val * 3 if val % 2 else val * 2 for val in list_in]
```

---

<sup>As a point of style, if your function's purpose is to modify the list in place, don't return the list.  That makes it clear that the input was mutated rather than returning a new list that was somehow constructed from the data in the original.</sup>

Comment: So i should store the modified list as a new list as opposed to returning the original list? Just for it be more readable?

Comment: @DakotaJones -- If a method returns `None`, it's not useful unless it has a side-effect (e.g. writing to the filesystem), or if it mutates the input arguments.  If a method returns _something else_, then it's _usually_ assumed that is the only action that it performed.  So, if you modify the original list, don't return anything.  If you create a new list based on the contents of the old list, that's the time to return something.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `enumerate`, because `for i in list` returns the element not the index.

```
for index, val in enumerate(list_in):
        if val % 2 == 0:
            list_in[index] = val* 2
        else:
            list_in[index] = val * 3
    return list_in
```